# Cassandra select all keys from map

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to select keys from the courses map in the student table below

```
CREATE TABLE student (
   studentid TEXT,
   courses map<TEXT, TEXT>,
   PRIMARY KEY (studentid)      
);
```

With this data inserted

```
UPDATE student SET courses = courses + { 'bio101': 'Intro to Bio'} where studentid='xyz' ;
UPDATE student SET courses = courses + { 'bio102': 'Advanced Bio'} where studentid='xyz' ;
UPDATE student SET courses = courses + { 'chem101': 'Intro to Chem'} where studentid='xyz' ;
```

I would like to select only the keys in the courses map. So

```
courseId
--------
'bio101'
'bio102'
'chem101'
```

I've tried variations of

```
select courses from student where studentid='xyz';
```

but I can't seem to select just that column.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [UDF](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateFunction.html) for this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION keys (input Map<Text, Text>) 
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT 
RETURNS Set<Text> 
LANGUAGE java AS 'return input.keySet();';
```

You have to enable UDF because it disabled by default. Find *enable_user_defined_functions* in *cassandra.yaml* and replace *false* with *true*. Restart your Cassandra.

Change a little your query.

```
select keys(courses) from student where studentid='xyz';
```